# web based Diagram drawing platform

Tags: architecture, workflow, uml

Is there (preferably) a php web solution that I can deploy on my dedicated server and therefor allow some users to collaborate (view/create/edit) on diagrams ?
I only know ready-hosted solutions like cacooa and I couldn't find any standalone software that I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for BPMN, if PHP is not a must have, you can have a look on the open source BPM engines. For example activiti (http://activiti.org/) or bonita (http://www.bonitasoft.org/) suites have tools for colaborative creating of BPMN diagrams. You do not need to install the complete suite.

For other UML diagrams it can be an option to use enterprise architect tool from Sparx Systems paired with subversion. So the users can check out , edit and check in the diagrams. The advantage of EA is the usage of the model. It can be reused over different diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe one of [these five web-based modelinig tools](http://modeling-languages.com/5-great-web-based-modeling-tools/) will work for you

Answer (score 1):

The only web-based multi user collaboration site that I know of would be Google Docs. (www.docs.google.com). As for a specific php, I do not know.

Comment: Thanks. But actually I'm looking for one that I could install on my own server and use it. Not cloud crap ;)